# How to fix overlapping absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, overlapping

How can I fix this? Do I have to specify height for Fieldset class? I don't want specify height to Fieldset by the way.

```css
.Identifier{
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Regular', sans-serif;
}

.Fieldset > input{
  width: 302px; padding: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}

.Fieldset > label{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 14px; left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="Identifier">
  <div class="Fieldset">
    <input type="text" name="Username">
    <label>Username or email</label>
  </div>
  <a href="">Forgot username or email?</a>
  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

[image: Photo is here]

Comment: Since `absolute` positioning takes elements out of document flow, there's no way that the element natively can tell it's overlapping another element. You need to specify height, or change your CSS to a non-absolute positioned element. Based on your markup, why are you positioning it absolutely?

Comment: This should be the only solution, right?

Comment: Changing the `position` property is going to be your best solution, unless you use some sort of percentage based padding/margin on the `button`. But, with your code there seems to be no reason to use absolute positioning.

Comment: Does it have to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: There will be animation like material design. @ShingaiMunyuki

Answer (score 2):

While you can make it so absolute positioning has a relative anchor point by placing it inside a parent with `position:relative` to achieve an overlap effect while keeping it aligned on different screen sizes.

From your code I think what you're trying to achieve is simply a field placeholder.

Which can be done just using `placeholder="your text here"` inside of the input tag. Which unlike if you try to do by overlapping the label element with the field, you'll end up with it obscuring the field text any user is trying to input.

```css
.Identifier {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Regular', sans-serif;
}

.Fieldset>input {
  padding: 12px;
}

.Fieldset>label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 14px;
  left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="Identifier">
    <div class="Fieldset">
      <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username or email">
  </div>
  <a href="">Forgot username or email?</a>
  <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```